# Show Highchart series horizontally below each other

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, visualization

I have created a multiple axes Highchart like this link: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes.

How can I show the series horizontally below each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define yAxis order to keep those series horizontally below each other.

define yAxis:0 ,1,2 and put series in same order as that of yAxis.

```
yAxis: [ 
        { 
        opposite : false,
        min: 0,
        top: 0,
        height: '31%',
        offset: 0   
       } //and so on 
       ]
```

[See a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4b33pvc2/)

Comment: Thanks! we can do it by changing top and heigth attrs of yAxis. Also update method do it dynamically.

Comment: `chart.yAxis[i].update({
                        height: seriesHeight.toString() + '%',
                        top: (100 - seriHeight).toString() + '%',
                        offset: 0,
                    });`